# How do I get AmazonId2 of a TransferUtilityUploadRequest

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using [AWS SDK for .NET 1.5.9.0](http://nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK) and changed

```
var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = key,
    FilePath = filePath,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};
try
{
    using (var pubtObjectResponse = client.PutObject(putObjectRequest))
    {
        Logger.Application.DebugFormat("uploaded {0} to {1} on bucket {2}, got id {3}", filePath, remotePath, bucketName, pubtObjectResponse.AmazonId2);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Application.Fatal(string.Format("could not upload {0} to {1} on bucket {2}", filePath, remotePath, bucketName), ex);
}
```

due to

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
>     at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
>     at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
>     at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>     at System.IO.Stream.Close()
>     at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getRequestStreamCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)
>     at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
>     at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndPutObject(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

by [suggestion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=285161) to

```
var transferUtilityUploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
    .WithBucketName(bucketName)
    .WithKey(key)
    .WithFilePath(filePath)
    .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead);
try
{
    transferUtility.Upload(transferUtilityUploadRequest);

    // how do I get success-state in here?
    // how do I get AmazonId2 in here?
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Application.Fatal(string.Format("could not upload {0} to {1} on bucket {2}", filePath, remotePath, bucketName), ex);
}
```

It's pretty obvious what I am trying to do, but how do I access the needed information?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using TransferUtility, you won't have access to AmazonId2, since the utility discards all responses.

TransferUtility.Upload is a blocking operation, so it will not return until the request is completed. However, you can monitor your upload by subscribing to an event on the request, like so:

```
uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent += (source, progress) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}% - {1} / {2}",
        progress.PercentDone,
        progress.TransferredBytes,
        progress.TotalBytes);
};
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but that's what i am already doing. unfortunately the success-state is still missing with subscribing to this event, as "failing" could happen anytime.

Comment: Can you clarify what success-state you are looking for? If TransferUtility.Upload returns without throwing an exception, it means that the upload request has succeeded. Aside from the progress event (and an exception in case of failure), this is the only "response" the Upload action has.

Comment: success-state would be a `bool` :) but your clarification that it's either an exception or none is sufficient!